# Create an exact copy of Analysis Services database with AMO

Tags: ssas, azure-analysis-services

I'm trying to automate the creation of an exact copy of an Analysis Services database using Microsoft.AnalysisServices namespace. My code is:

```
using (var server = new Server())
{
    server.Connect(connString);
    var newDb = server.Databases.GetByName(dbName).Clone();
    newDb.Name = newDbName;
    newDb.ID = server.Databases.GetNewID();
    server.Databases.Add(newDb);
    newDb.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
    server.Disconnect();
}
```

However it seems it creates an empty database instead because from SSMS i'm not able to see any tables, datasources and similar (check my screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4dC.png)).

Is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

@gmarchi
You need to clone the child Model object using [Model.clone() method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.tabular.model.clone?view=analysisservices-dotnet) as well to make to make it work. You can add Model using code like below -

```
        var connString = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=asazure://westus2.asazure.windows.net/xxxxxxxxxxxx:rw";
        var dbName = "AW Internet Sales";
        var newDbName = "CloneDb";
        
        using (var server = new Server())
        {
            server.Connect(connString);
            var newDb = server.Databases.GetByName(dbName).Clone();
            var newModel = server.Databases.GetByName(dbName).Model.Clone();
            
            newDb.Name = newDbName;
            newDb.ID = server.Databases.GetNewID();
            newDb.Model = newModel;

            server.Databases.Add(newDb);
            newDb.Update(UpdateOptions.ExpandFull);
            server.Disconnect();
        }
```

Please find below the screenshot after the code run.
[image]

Please let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much! The solution seems working! However may I ask you also if there is a way to exclude every role (and relative role members obviously) from the clone during the process?

Comment: I do not think that is possible but you can remove the roles from cloned model object after it is created in the code by using something like below - foreach(Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular.ModelRole r in server.Databases.GetByName(dbName).Model.Roles)
                {
                    newModel.Roles.Remove(r.Name);                  
                }